# Which code is cleaner with more efficiency?

Tags: python, function

This is the code that I wrote

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60 and not is_weekend:
    return True
  if cigars >=40 and is_weekend:
      return True
  else:
      return False
```

This is the code that was marked as "Their solution"

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend:
    return (cigars >= 40)
  else:
    return (cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60)
```

In my opinion my code is easier to read but I might be looking at this subjectively so please let me know what you think because I'd love to improve my code.

Comment: Technically this is a matter of opinion (and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow) - but I'd be surprised if many disagreed with me that the second version ("their solution") is much cleaner

Comment: FYI in Python you can write `40 <= cigars <= 60` to chain the conditions.

Comment: [codereview.se] is a better place to ask questions about coding style. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users before reposting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the second is generally considered cleaner. Notice this in your code:

```
  if cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60 and not is_weekend:
    return True
```

The `if` statement is checking whether or not the condition specified is `True`. 
So `cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60 and not is_weekend` gets evaluated before the program continues.
 If it evaluates to `True`, you have it return `True`, but that is repetitive.

Consider:

```
if True:
    return True
```

when we can just do:

```
return True
```

Comment: oh wow thanks a lot I actually didn't know that that was even possible.